# How to change screen resolution on my 10 year old Compaq Presario 2500

Tags: drivers, updates, resolution, screen

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my old laptop as Windows XP was simply crawling. Ubuntu is a lot lot better..MANY THANKS! But my screen resolution/quality is not great. My display is RS200 ( RADEON IGP330M/340M/350M ).

Is there a way for me to optimise my display? I don't know if the driver was updated while installing Ubuntu or if it can. All advice are greatly appreciated.

Guna

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ubuntu Documentation Radeon Driver wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver), you are already using the correct graphics driver for your system, that is the free, open source driver for many ATI graphics cards that comes preinstalled with the Ubuntu default installation. Your graphics card is on the Ubuntu Documentation Radeon Driver wiki's list of Radeon graphics cards that have good 3D acceleration support.

So before you consider trying to install a graphics driver that is not recommended for your system, you should check to see if it is possible for you to change your screen resolution using an application called *Resolution Switcher* from the Ubuntu Software Center. Resolution Switcher allows you to change your screen resolution in a graphic user interface. However what usually happens is that you already have the best screen resolution, and Resolution Switcher doesn't give you any options to improve it.